# Is 'using' keyword a preprocesor directive?

Tags: c++, directive, preprocessor-directive

Is the `using` directive a preprocessor directive?

If not: Besides preprocessor and using directives, are there any other directives in C++?

Comment: Why don't you look that up in the language definition? The latest ISO draft is always online (simply google "C++ ISO draft"). When you are done, post your own answer and cash in twice.

Comment: *? ... ? ... ? ... ?* One question per question.

Comment: Hint: the preprocessor is a glorified text substitution system and doesn't really know anything about C++ syntax or semantics.

Comment: For all those who have given a negative vote, I am a beginner to OOP trying to self-learn the paradigm. There are a lot of similar words which mean slightly different things which is a little bit confusing so trying to make sense.

Comment: I have narrowed the question, hopefully enough to re-open but not too much to mutilate it.

Comment: Because I can technically not answer currently, here it is as comment: The [latest standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) uses the word "directive" to describe several things: (1) The most common one is the *preprocessor directive* which always begins with a `#`, so that a using directive is clearly not one. (2) A *formatting directive* in `printf` etc. (3) The *using directive* you ask about, which is technically a *declaration* (p. 1422) because it introduces a name. (4) A few other places, e.g. "function reserve() is a directive" (p. 746).

Comment: ... So the term is not strictly defined. The standard uses it mostly for the preprocessor directives, and the other uses seem to be when nothing is really "done" (declarations, reserve(), format definitions).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you think a keyword is a preprocessor directive? They are two substantially different things.

To make it clear, a preprocessor directive **always** starts with a hash and must occupy at least a whole line. A keyword is instead a "word" (may contain underscores). So they have no commonness.

Your answers:

> Is the directive `using` a preprocessor directive?

No. It is a directive but not a **preprocessor** directive

> Is it handled by the preprocessor or the compiler?

It's handled by the compiler, as a "directive" for name lookup.

> Also, what is a directive?

You can safely believe whatever that doesn't compiles into actual, executable code is directive. This is a very broad question and a full answer won't fit here.

You may want to [look up "directive" in a dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/directive).

> Is 'using' a directive or a keyword?

Both.

> Am I right in understanding that All directives are not 'pre-processor directive' but all preprocessor directives are directives?

Probably right. That makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. My confusion is when they say using directive is it a preprocessor directive or just a directive? ie the word 'directive' is different than the word  'preprocessor directive'.

Comment: ie exactly my confusion. You say directive start with hash but that directive is the preprocessor directive. But using directive is not a preprocessor directive ryt?

Comment: @GRANZER I guess I misunderstood "directive". See the new answers.